# XSL:FO make output Bold with font:weight

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

Hi I want to make my output with xsl:fo bold but with font:weight="bold" nothing happens.

My xslt file:

```
  <xsl:template match="out">
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>
```

My xml file:

```
<root>
     <out>BLA BAL BLA</out>
</root>
```

My output is:

```
BLA BAL BLA ( not bold)
```

I use Saxon-He: 9.5 and xslt 2.0

Comment: You need to also show the xml input, without it we can only guess.

Comment: What is the nothing happens? Do you get output but not bold? Or are you getting nothing or an error? If you are getting output then perhaps you do not have a bold font registered. If you are getting an error, perhaps you have different issues as you have only showed one snippet of your xsl.

Comment: I get an output but not bold

Comment: Your template never applies to the content. Please show a _complete_ XSLT stylesheet that allows to reproduce the problem. Then, we can point out where you went wrong.

Comment: should i poste the whole xslt file ?

Comment: You should post a [**minimal**, complete and verifiable sample of your XSLT code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MathiasMüller i already found my problem , I used an font how can't print bold text ^^
I found the problem because i trim my xslt file ^^
thank you
How can i upvote you now ?

Comment: You can't - what kind of font does not support bold text? Now you should either 1) delete the question because the problem was caused by something unrelated to the question and therefore it will never be useful for anybody else 2) edit it and give enough information for someone to identify the problem and write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I already found my Problem i use font="ArialMT" and these font can't print bold text.